# Just need to check whether WSS server is On/Off via WSS client using .Net System.Net.WebSockets with Certificate?

Tags: c#, wss, clientwebsocket, system.net.websockets

Why always getting error Cannot find the requested object? See trace detail in code my comment.

I need to implement WSS client and check WSS server availability using certificates.

But as try to create object of `X509Certificate2`, getting error:

> Cannot find the requested object

```cs
bool IsWssConnAlive(string WssUrl)
{
    bool flg = false;
    try
    {
        //string _certificateKeyStorePath = @"E:\bk\WSS\gateway\test\keystoreserver.der";
        string _certificateKeyStorePath = @"E:\bk\WSS\gateway\test\keystoreserver.p12";
        X509Certificate2 x509_1 = new X509Certificate2(_certificateKeyStorePath, "test@123");

        /*
         * Above X509Certificate2 statement aways giving error : "Cannot find the requested object.\r\n"}
         * I tried .der, p21, .jks getting same error
         * stack trace details :->
         
         *    at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
              at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
              at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
              at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
              at Test_WssConnectivity.Program.IsWssConnAlive(String WssUrl, Int32 CheckTimeInSec) in E:\Development\SolutionForTestProject\Test_WssConnectivity\Program.cs:line 142

         */

        ClientWebSocket websocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        websocket.Options.ClientCertificates.Add(x509_1);


        X509CertificateCollection xcol = new X509CertificateCollection();
        xcol.Add(x509_1);

        websocket.Options.ClientCertificates = xcol;

        //connect to URL
        websocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(WssUrl), CancellationToken.None);

        //Now checking actaul status
        if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            flg = true;
        }
        else if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Closed)
        {
            flg = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        flg = false;
    }

    return flg;
}
```

Comment: This error can be associated when you're using invalid certificates.  Can you say how they were generated?

Comment: I have .jks certificates that is working properly when we attached in Nifi interface manually. but via c# code its giving error. and I also converted .jks to.P12 & .Der format using keytool command but still getting same error.